# On interpreting the statistical significance of R squared

Tags: correlation, spss, descriptive-statistics, pearson-r

I have performed a linear regression analysis to two series of data, each of which has `50` values. I did the analysis in SPSS and as a result got a table which says that my `adjusted R squared` is `0.145` and its significance is `0.004`.

Being `0.004 < 0.05`, I assume my `adjusted R squared` is significant.

1) Does it mean my `adjusted R squared` is *credible*?

2) What does happen if you get a significance which is `> 0.05`? Does it imply the `adjusted R squared` can be trusted with credibility but also that the two datasets are not or poorly correlated?

**EDIT**

I think I can condense my last question into: does a `statistically non-significant R squared` nullify the validity of the calculated `R squared`?

Comment: What distinctions, exactly, are you making between "credible," "correlated," and "significant"?  Although the latter two terms have commonly understood meanings, the first one is ambiguous.

Comment: Well, it sounds ambiguous to me that there is a procedure which computes `R` and then tells you if it is statistically significant. In this context I think I can maintain *credible* means acceptable or trustworthy.

Comment: I think I can condense my last question into: does a `statistically non-significant R squared` nullify the validity of the calculated `R squared`?

Comment: I suspect many of your uncertainties about the meaning of this output may be addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31 : please take a look.